# Specific logback key-value pair in format

Tags: java, logback

Logback allows adding key-value pairs to events. But the only way I've found to use them is the %kvp option in the formatter, that just dumps all of the key="value" pairs.

Isn't there any way to insert the values (I don't care about logging the key), separated at specific places in the format ?

It seems to be doable with %X for MDC elements, but not for simple key pairs.

Alternatively I guess I could use MDC for this, but then I would be basically changing my value for each event. It did not seem to me it was meant for this kind of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As luck would have it I also ran into this problem today!

It's not a fantastic solution but one way would be to use a regex like so, assuming you have a property in your key value pair list named `myProperty`, and assuming that, like most people, you are using the pattern encoder:

`%replace(%kvp){'.*myProperty="([^"]+)".*', '$1'}`

breaking down the regex:

- `.*` - match any character 0 or more times
- `myProperty=` - exact string match
- `"([^"])"` - one or more of any non-double quote character which are between the next two double quotes, place into capture group 1
- `.*` - any character 0 or more times

then $1 in the second argument replaces the whole key-value string with the contents of capture group 1

Now, we just need to remove this key-value from the `%kvp` output we put in our log message, it is similar. Assuming you have some `additionalData` field in your log message:

`additionalData={%replace(%kvp{DOUBLE}){'[\s]{0,1}myProperty="[^"]"', ''}}`

Please note this regex could leave extra whitespace in the resulting string if it is the first element. To remedy this you can wrap this regex in a second one to remove any leading whitespace:

`additionalData={%replace(%replace(%kvp{DOUBLE}){'[\s]{0,1}myProperty="[^"]"', ''}}){'^\s+', ''}`

It's terse, but you can play around with the regex at regex101 or some similar interactive tool.

If you'd like to avoid all this regex ugliness, you can also try registering a [custom conversion specifier](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier) to do the heavy lifting for you, I have not tried this route though.

Comment: Still feels weird that there isn't a direct way. But I guess if you had to go through that there isn't. Nice idea, just started playing with logback and did not think of using the %replace. Seems like wasted computation time, but that should work. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely agree with you. I am also not too experienced with logback, perhaps the more idiomatic way would be to use one of these custom conversion specifiers. I don’t think the compute requirements will be too bad but profile if you have massive usage. In any case most people are probably using the reflection oriented conversion specifiers like filename and linenumber, so compared to that I don’t think a couple regexs should have huge impact.